# R typecast NA vs string

Tags: r, casting, na

I had a problem with some of my code and I fixed it but don't fully understand why the error was an error

The code looked like:

```
for(i in 1:3){df = rbind.fill(z, data.frame(id=i,
data=if(is.null(x$results[[i]]$synopsis$data))    
{NA}else{x$results[[i]]$synopsis$data}))}
```

The issue I had was, if the first data value was indeed null, I would get `NA` but then for the second and third I would either get another `NA` or if there was data I wouldn't get it, I would get `1`.

If the first value was data, then I would get the data and for the other two I would either get `NA` or the correct data.

I'm not a computer scientist but a dev who sits near me (but doesnt know R) suggested it was something to do with different typecasts of `NA` and a string. To solve the issue I changed the `NA` to `"0"` (I suppose `"NA"` would work too).

I'd just like a more thorough explanation into what was happening. My layman's understanding is if `NA` was the first result, then every result is in that "format" where something is either `NA` or not and not is handled as `1` which is kinda of like a Boolean response?

Example:

```
my.list <- list(list(),structure(
     list(
         experience = structure(
             list(
                 start = "Hi"
             ),.Names = c("start")),
         `_meta` = structure(
             list(weight = 1L, `_sources` = list(structure(
                 list(`_origin` = "a"), .Names = "_origin"
             ))),.Names = c("weight", "_sources"))),.Names = c("experience", "_meta")))

my.list[[1]]$experience$start
    NULL
my.list[[2]]$experience$start
    [1] "Hi"


  df <- NULL
    for(i in 1:2){df = rbind.fill(df, data.frame(id=i,
data=if(is.null(my.list[[i]]$experience$start))                                                 
    {NA}else{my.list[[i]]$experience$start}))}
```

Then

```
  df2 <- NULL
for(i in 1:2){df2 = rbind.fill(df2, data.frame(id=i,                                               
data=if(is.null(my.list[[i]]$experience$start))                                                    
{"NA"}else{my.list[[i]]$experience$start}))}
```

Results:

```
df:              df2:

id data        id data
1   NA         1   NA
2   1          2   HI
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome for `df` ? Only one row with the experience start id2 "Hi" or two rows?

Comment: updated with results - df1 is wrong, and I'd like to know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olivia, thanks for clarifications.
You are nearly there. As you loop, indeed the first iteration will determine the class of the column `data` of your output data.frame `df`.

In scenario 1, you can have a better idea by going through the loop step by step:

```
df <- NULL
i=1
df = rbind.fill(df, data.frame(id=i,
    data=if(is.null(my.list[[i]]]$experience$start)) {NA}
    else{my.list[[i]]$experience$start}))
df

  id data
1  1   NA
```

Then, have a look at class of `df$data`

```
class(df$data)
[1] "logical"
```

Which is derived from: `mode(NA)`  (logical).

As an alternative way, when you store data related in your set of experiments in a list, you should try to use a "R-ish" way to manipulate this list.

For instance, you can try:

```
sapply(my.list, FUN=function(element)element$experience$start)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "Hi"
```

Which highlights that you tries to gather together sets of incompatibles contents: simplification can't go simpler than this list -- if you `unlist` you would dismiss this meaningful `NULL`

Comment: The NULL or NA are required such that the number of rows is correct. That is why there is an id column based on i. My actual data is more complicated, pulling from nested lists that come from a json response from an api. Using "0" seems to work. Ive not checked and seen if 0 would also work or whether being numeric would mess up the characters following